# WPF locking workstation programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, events, keyboard

I am trying to automate workstation locking after the occurence of a WPF event. The solution is supposed to work for both x64 and x86 architectures.

I've tried the method **LockWorkStation()** accessible through **user32.dll** but it works only on x86 architecture. Is there an alternative or a specific configuration to make it work on both architectures? I thought about sending the **LWin + L** keyboard shortcut but the **SendKeys.Send** method does not seem to be usable in WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string winDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
string exec = $@"{winDir}\System32\rundll32.exe";
string command = "user32.dll,LockWorkStation";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exec, command);
```

works on my win10 x64

[image]